# When recall methods Fragment not attached to a context Error. What context should i send and receive?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-fragments

At first my sendData method is working but when I call it from another activity it has 'not attached to a context.' error.

When I opened it looks work, but after i delete some data it wasn't work.

Here is my code.

DeleteDialog.java

```
public class DeleteDialog extends android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment {
private Context mContext;
@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_delete_dialog, container, false);

    mContext=this.getContext();

...

ok_btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(editText.getText().toString().equals("")){
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), "과목명을 입력해 주세요", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }else{

                dbHelper = new DBHelper(mContext);
                db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                dbHelper.deleteColum(editText.getText().toString());
                timeTableFragment.sendData(mContext);
                getDialog().dismiss();
            }

        }
    });
```

TimeTableFragment.java

```
public class TimeTableFragment extends Fragment {
private Context mContext;


public void sendData(Context context) { //get data and draw to layout
    dbHelper = new DBHelper(context);
    db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    dbHelper.onCreate(db);
    String date = "", start = "", end = "", title = "", color = "";

    ArrayList<SubjectItem> timetable_data;
    timetable_data = dbHelper.getDataTimetable(); //get data from sql
    SimpleDateFormat sf = new SimpleDateFormat("HHmm");

    int resID = 0;
    int mok;
    Date a, b;
    long diff, min;
    View view = getView();

    for (int i = 0; i < timetable_data.size(); i++) {  // draw to layout
        date = timetable_data.get(i).getSub_date();
        start = timetable_data.get(i).getSub_start();
        end = timetable_data.get(i).getSub_end();
        title = timetable_data.get(i).getSub_title();
        color = timetable_data.get(i).getSub_color();

        if (date.substring(0, 2).equals("Th")) {
            date = "h";
            Log.d("ㄹㄹ","목요일 : " +date);
        }
        date = date.toLowerCase().substring(0, 1);
        Log.d("ㄹㄹ","바깥의 데이터 : " +date);
        start = start.replace(":", "");
        end = end.replace(":", "");


        try {
            a = sf.parse(start);
            b = sf.parse(end);
            diff = b.getTime() - a.getTime();
            min = (diff / (1000 * 60));
            mok = (int) min / 30;

            Log.d(TAG,"title " +title + " start :  " + start +","+ a.getTime()+ " / end : " +  end+","+b.getTime() +   "   date : " + date);

            for (int k = 0; k < mok; k++) {

                if (mok != 1) {

                    if (end.substring(2, 4).equals("30")) {
                        end = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(end) - 30);
                        if (end.length() == 3) end = "0" + end;
                        Log.d(TAG, " 그리기 title :  " +title );
                        //Log.d(TAG , "콘텍스트 : " + getContext().getPackageName());
         Error ->       resID = getResources().getIdentifier(date + end, "id", getContext().getPackageName());
                        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(resID);
                        textView.setText(title);
                        paintTimetable(textView,color);

                    } else {
                        end = Integer.toString(Integer.parseInt(end) - 70);
                        if (end.length() == 3) end = "0" + end;
                        Log.d("Contxet " , "콘텍스트 : " + getContext().getPackageName());
                        resID = getResources().getIdentifier(date + end, "id", getContext().getPackageName());
                        TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(resID);
                        textView.setText(title);
                        paintTimetable(textView,color);
                        Log.d(TAG, " 그리기 title :  "  +title);
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d("Contxet " , "콘텍스트 : " + getContext().getPackageName());
                    resID = getResources().getIdentifier(date + start, "id", getContext().getPackageName());
                    TextView textView = (TextView) view.findViewById(resID);
                    textView.setText(title);
                    paintTimetable(textView,color);

                }
            }
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);

    try {

        mContext=getContext();
    } catch (ClassCastException e) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Exception" + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

DBHelper.java

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

}

... 

public void deleteColum(String name)
{
    String DELETE = "DELETE FROM " + TABLE_TIMETABLE + " WHERE " + KEY_TITLE + "='" + name + "'";

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL(DELETE);
    Log.d("dd", "sql deleted  :  " + name);

}
```

And Error message :

```
Fragment TimeTableFragment{f4aa844} not attached to a context.
```

In DB Insert, Delete are perfectly works but after call sendData method in DeleteDialog occurred 'not attached to a context'.

What context should I send and receive?

Comment: Your `DeleteDialog` is already a `Fragment` that is attached - why are you using some different `TimeTableFragment` to send your data? Where do you add the `TimeTableFragment` to a `FragmentManager`?

Comment: @ianhanniballake Actually sendData should be renamed to drawData. In DeleteDialog, delete some column and redraw the data using TimeTableFragemnt sendData method. FragmentManger is in MainActivity it's consist of bottom navigation view.

Answer (score 0):

All database tasks should be done in async (another thread). It might take a while and after job is done you should come back to main thread and check if the view still exist, this way you will avoid memory leaks and error that you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Use `getApplicationContext()` for initializing your DBHelper. This will ensure proper context of your app and does create the error you are receiving.

**Addtional Info:**
Make your DBHelper as Singleton it will optimize your app resources.